# Spring TestRestTemplate parse Error instead of HttpClientErrorException thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am writing tests for my spring boot application.
When writing tests for error responses I noticed that TestRestTemplate client throws parse exception (it's error response, so format is different that standard response) for the following test:

```
@Test
fun `post should return 404 if object does not exists`() {
    // expect
    restTemplate.exchange(
        localUrl("/api/v1/data/not_exists/"),
        HttpMethod.POST,
        RequestClass(data = randomString()),
        ResponseClass::class.java
    )
}
```

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type
```

According to spring documentation `HttpClientErrorException` error should be thrown.
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE_to_3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html

There is an ugly solution where I cant set response type to `Nothing`, but error response content will be lost.

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    localUrl("/api/v1/data/not_exists/"),
    HttpMethod.POST,
    RequestClass(data = randomString()),
    Nothing::class.java
)
```

Is this possible to make `TestRestTemplate`/`RestTemplate` to throw actual `HttpClientErrorException` instead of failing on parsing response?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68134196/parsing-an-exception-instead-of-list-of-entities-is-not-working-when-using-test
similar question