# Parsing an exception instead of List of entities is not working, when using TestRestTemplate and MockRestServiceServer

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jsonparser, mockrestserviceserver

I have a simple controller ([CODE](https://github.com/joergi/tryouts/blob/main/kotlin-mockrestserver/src/main/kotlin/io/joergi/kotlinmockrestserver/controller/Controller.kt))

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profiles" , produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
class Controller(@Autowired val restClient: RestClient) {

    @GetMapping("/simple-get")
    fun simpleGetCall(): List<Profile> {
        restClient.callClientGet()
        return listOf(
                    Profile("firstname1", "lastname1"),
                    Profile("firstname2", "lastname2"))
    }
}
```

the controller is calling the RestClient which is making a client call ([CODE](https://github.com/joergi/tryouts/blob/main/kotlin-mockrestserver/src/main/kotlin/io/joergi/kotlinmockrestserver/client/RestClient.kt))

```
@Service
class RestClient(@Autowired val restTemplate: RestTemplate) {
    fun callClientGet(){
        try {
            restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "/profiles/simple-get",
                Number::class.java
            )
        }catch(exception: Exception){
            throw MyClientCallException("this is an exception")
        }
    }
}
```

MyClientCallException looks like this ([CODE](https://github.com/joergi/tryouts/blob/main/kotlin-mockrestserver/src/main/kotlin/io/joergi/kotlinmockrestserver/exception/MyClientCallException.kt))

```
class MyClientCallException(message: String) :
    ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message)
```

I have 3 functional tests in my class ([CODE](https://github.com/joergi/tryouts/blob/main/kotlin-mockrestserver/src/test/kotlin/io/joergi/kotlinmockrestserver/controller/FunctionalControllerTest.kt))
I use the `org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer` as server

```
@Test
fun `when calling service, and client returns Accepted, status should be OK`() {

    val responseType: ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>> =
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>>() {}

    mockServer?.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(URI("http://localhost:8082/profiles/simple-get")))
        ?.andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
        ?.andRespond(
            MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

    val response = testRestTemplate.exchange(
        "/profiles/simple-get",
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        responseType
    )
    response.statusCode shouldBe HttpStatus.OK
    response.body?.size shouldBe 2
}
```

This test is working as expected. The client is returning `ACCEPTED` and the server call is returning the `List<Profile>`

the second test is failing.

```
@Test
fun `when calling service, and client timeout, it should return 500 - not working, problems with parsing`() {

    val responseType: ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>> =
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>>() {}

    mockServer?.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(URI("http://localhost:8082/profiles/simple-get")))
        ?.andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
        ?.andRespond(
            MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

    val response = testRestTemplate.exchange(
        "/profiles/simple-get",
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        responseType
    )
    response.statusCode shouldBe HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
}
```

When I do the client call, it's faking a time out exception, something which can always happen.
Then the returned `Exceptions` can't be parsed to the `List<Profile>` which then give the following error:

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while
> extracting response for type [java.util.List<? extends model.Profile>]
> and content type [application/json]; nested exception is
> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type
> `java.util.ArrayList<model.Profile>` from Object value (token
> `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<model.Profile>` from
> Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)  at [Source:
> (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]

The next 2 tests are workarounds, but both are not OK for me.

```
@Test
fun `when calling service, and client timeout, it should return 500 working `() {

    val responseType: ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>> =
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>>() {}

    mockServer?.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(URI("http://localhost:8082/profiles/simple-get")))
        ?.andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
        ?.andRespond(
            MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))


    assertThrows<RestClientException> {
        testRestTemplate.exchange(
            "/profiles/simple-get",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            null,
            responseType
        )
    }

}
```

The response type is still as in the original. but it's catching the RestClientException.
I was expecting to throw my MyClientCallException and also catch it. (it returns 500, which is good, but I want to see my own exception. This is just an example, maybe I want to return a different error code)

```
@Test
fun `when calling service, and client timeout, it should return 500 - but response type is wrong`() {

    mockServer?.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.requestTo(URI("http://localhost:8082/profiles/simple-get")))
        ?.andExpect(MockRestRequestMatchers.method(HttpMethod.GET))
        ?.andRespond(
            MockRestResponseCreators.withStatus(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))

    val response = testRestTemplate.exchange(
        "/profiles/simple-get",
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        String::class.java
    )

    response.statusCode shouldBe HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

}
```

Second one: I just parse everything as a String, which is helping to solve it.
but I'm awaiting originally a `List<Profile>` so, telling the `testRestTemplate`, that I want just a String as a response would fake the test.

Is there any way, to make this better or solve this problem?

You can checkout the complete project: https://github.com/joergi/tryouts/tree/main/kotlin-mockrestserver for better tryout.

P.S. I know, this question is similar to [Spring TestRestTemplate parse Error instead of HttpClientErrorException thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199902/spring-testresttemplate-parse-error-instead-of-httpclienterrorexception-thrown) but it is still unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

*Then the returned Exceptions can't be parsed to the List which then give the following error:* - You are asking jackson to map exception to profile list which is obviously failing.

Why not use response type as MyClientCallException instead of ParameterizedTypeReference<List> ? - this should allow jackson to parse the exception response stream to MyClientCallException

Also if you would like to know why `RestClientException` is not treated same as other client errors - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/b84fefc430cdf10d428b02f6d61009b7460ae26f#diff-309e077b6d47c54260c59a899971042456c5e03eb5e96e5121c31842b55deedb